# How can I style ::before speech bubble chevrons as desired?

Tags: css

I have made these little speech bubble kind of warnings, and I want to use `::before` to style the the little chevron [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAH7j.png) in white with the same dark background `#1f262c` and the salmon border on just 2 sides `#da6265`

Ive tried with the below but its not the effect I'm looking for where is all looks like one speech bubble

```
small::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 11px;
    border: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: position it lower with bottom: n px. then rotate it to get the rotated style.

Answer (score 1):

Using :before as the black background and :after as a larger salmon colored chevron behind the :before should get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I got a really good look as [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqxlB.png) I would not have thought of the rotate

```
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    border-left: 1.3px solid #db6265;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotate(45deg);
    left: -7px;
    background-color: #1f262c;
    border-bottom: 1.3px solid #db6265;
    top: 11px;
```